# PHP and .htaccess doesn't allow $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess document in the root of my webserver with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Everything works perfect I can easily explode the link in PHP using the follinw code:

```
$params = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump($params);
```

Now I want to do a `$_GET['name']` request but this isn't working, it is just pasting it in the params array so I am not available to get the code using `$_GET`.

Do you know how to fix this? The problem is the .htaccess file I suppose.

Comment: well, what do you expect? If you're not passing any query args in the url, then php has NOTHING to put into $_GET. e.g. if you have `example.com/foo/bar`, then $_GET will be empty, because there's no `?key=val` portion to pull apart. you'd need to have `example.com/foo/bar?baz=qux`, in which case $params will contain foo/bar, and $_GET will have baz->qux.

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? "it is just pasting it in the params array" - you mean it appears on the end of the last element of the `$params` array in your example? (This part is expected.)

Comment: @MarcB The OP does not state what the requested URL is. Why do you assume there is no query string?

Comment: @w3d: if there was a query string, there'd be data in $_GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can add the `{QUERY_STRING}`

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

This should append all GET params to the new url.

Comment: By not including a query string (ie. a `?`) in the substitution, the query string on the request should already be passed through to the substitution. Manually adding `?%{QUERY_STRING}` is not required.

Comment: Good point I testet this AND you are right ;) Well than I think my answer will not help the OP

Comment: @YanickvanBarneveld Curious - because this really shouldn't (at least on Apache with the code given in your question). There would seem to be _something else_ going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php [QSA,L]`

[`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) basically appends query string every time, and [`L`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) means to stop processing other rules (if any) once this one is matched.

Comment: The `QSA` flag is not required in this instance. The query string from the request is automatically appended on the substitution. You only need the `QSA` flag if you are adding an _additional_ query string in the substitution and you need to merge the two.